# change css of one div by hovering on another div

Tags: css

I have two containers with text. I want to increase the text size of one of the texts by hovering on the other by only using CSS. The method I saw on a different SO post is not working for me. What is the right way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```css
.top p {
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.bottom p {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom:hover + .top {
  font-size: 6vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='top'>
    <p>scale</p>
  </div>
  <div class='bottom'>
    <p>hover</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be sure: is `div.bottom` _always_ immediately after `div.top` ? That is, there will never be anything in between? If so, then you can use `div.top:hover+div.bottom`.

Comment: BTW, I think you should use ids instead of classes. The implication is that there will be exactly one of each, rather than maybe some more.

Comment: @Manngo that wont work take a look at my comment on the answer below.

Comment: Ah, you want to go either way. For that, you will need some JavaScript. CSS doesn’t (yet) have a reverse selector.

Comment: @Manngo yeah that's what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a sample which changes the CSS of the other element.

Unfortunately, the CSS `:hover` pseudo class, as well as CSS selectors make remote controlling other elements tricky, so you will have to use JavaScript.

In this case, hovering over one `div` triggers the `mouseover` event, which is set to add the `other` class to the other element. Moving the mouse out triggers the `mouseout` event, which will remove that class.

I have written the JavaScript in four separate parts, but, with more experience, it is possible to be a little more subtle.

To illustrate the point, I simply change the background colour. Obviously, this is where you might do something more meaningful.

```js
document.querySelector('div.top').onmouseover=function(event) {
  document.querySelector('div.bottom').classList.add('other');
}
document.querySelector('div.top').onmouseout=function(event) {
  document.querySelector('div.bottom').classList.remove('other');
}
document.querySelector('div.bottom').onmouseover=function(event) {
  document.querySelector('div.top').classList.add('other');
}
document.querySelector('div.bottom').onmouseout=function(event) {
  document.querySelector('div.top').classList.remove('other');
}
```

```css
div.other {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='top'>
    <p>scale</p>
  </div>
  <div class='bottom'>
    <p>hover</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top:hover + .bottom{font-size:30px;}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='top'><p>scale</p></div>
  <div class='bottom'><p>hover</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no this won't work! I need to hover on bottom and scale top!!

Comment: Do you want to change.top font size or .bottom?

Comment: i want to chance font size of top